# How to "forget" network wifi configuration in windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

In previos Windows versions I can to "click" forget the network configuration for a given wifi name.

I could'n do it in Windows 10. I try to "right click" in the network name but nothing apears. With a "left click" I see the disconect button, but lack of "forget" button. I'm looking in "settings" Network & Internet, Wi-Fi, Wireless Network Connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Click Start.
- Click Settings.
- Click Network & Internet.
- Click Wi-Fi.
- Click Manage Wi-Fi Settings.
- Scroll down to "Manage known networks"
- Click the network you want to forget.
- Click Forget.

[image]

[Picture source, and more info](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29889/~/how-to-delete-a-wireless-network-profile-in-windows-10)

Comment: Is there a program (wifi-manager) which makes this more accessible?